# Why is Chrome now blanking all page content that is off screen, re-renders it a full second after scrolling

Tags: google-chrome, macos-ventura

Chrome recently started this severe janky behavior. When I scroll ANY PAGE, the content is blank for a full second before Chrome renders the content. Even when I scroll back up to previously rendered content, it is blank for a full second before Chrome rerenders the content! It is super annoying!

What broke? And how do I fix it? Use the flags page to demonstrate the behavior: chrome://flags/

I'm running the latest Chrome version on the latest Beta Mac OS:

Chrome Version 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (arm64)

macOS Ventura 13.2 Beta(a)

Answer (score 3):

I found a fix/workaround that restores smooth scrolling and everything is already rendered! Go to [chrome://flags/](https://chrome://flags/) and disable "Threaded Scrolling." I haven't noticed any page performance degradation either.

Comment: Thank you man, you have saved me, its been 3 days of optimizing a website, but this was the actual problem

Comment: When I search for "Threaded Scrolling" I get "No matching experiments".